# Match Regular Expressions patterns if exist, else

Tags: regex

Here is what I am trying to achieve. Given a certain set of data I am trying to get the entire row that contains the matching regular expressions that I have.

Essentially, given a data set such as this

```
AFAM 002A AFAM & DEV AM HIS/GV 03 46493 3 LEC D2 70 P 20/15 W 1800-2045 08/24/16-12/12/16 WSQ 207 K WHITE 
AFAM 102 AFRO-AMER MUSIC 01 47200 3 LEC P 5/30 W 1800-2045 08/24/16-12/12/16 MUS 250 V GROCE-ROBERTS 
AFAM 125 THE BLACK FAMILY 01 47198 3 LEC P 16/40 M 1800-2045 08/24/16-12/12/16 CCB 101 S MILLNER 
AFAM 152 THE BLACK WOMAN 01 47199 3 LEC P 8/40 T 1800-2045 08/24/16-12/12/16 CL 111 R WILSON 
AFAM 159 ECON ISSUES BLKCM 01 47197 3 LEC P 11/40 MW 1330-1445 08/24/16-12/12/16 CL 234 R WILSON 
AFAM 180 INDIVIDUAL STUDIES 01 46982 3 SUP P 0/10 TBA TBA 08/24/16-12/12/16
```

The regex that I have created basically groups the following into..

1. Course ID eg. AFAM 002A
2. Course Name eg. AFRO-AMER MUSIC
3. Start date
4. end date
5. Professor Name **(This is the value that I want to be optional)**

The problem that I am having now is that for the optional value, instead of what I what which is to **check if it exist, if not then leave empty**. If someone could show me the correct way to do this I would greatly appreciated it.

Essentially this part of my regular expression `([A-Z][\s][A-Z]+[-]*[A-Z]+)?` Needs to be included if it exist, I understand that that's how the `?` operator is supposed to work, however I cant seem to find the right keyword for this question so here I am

```
([A-Z]+[\s][0-9]+[A-Z]*)(.+)[\s][0-9]+[\s][0-9]+.+(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)-(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)[\s]([A-Z][\s][A-Z]+[-]*[A-Z]+)?
```

**The Expected results for this dataset for the last two rows should be**

```
{ [ (AFAM 159), (ECON ISSUES BLKCM), (08/24/16), (12/12/16), (R WILSON)],
[(AFAM 180), (INDIVIDUAL STUDIES), (08/24/16), (12/12/16), ()]
 }
```

Comment: What did you want to leave empty? What are the expected results?

Comment: I apologize,  added the expected results in an edit

Comment: Your regex does not match `CL 234` in the last but one line. Try [`([A-Z]+\s\d+[A-Z]*)(.+)\s\d+\s\d+.+(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)-(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)\s(?:.*?([A-Z]\s[A-Z]+-*[A-Z]+))?`](https://regex101.com/r/LjKmw9/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex does not match `CL 234` in the last but one line. You need to consume it. However, just adding `.*?` won't work, you need to make your optional pattern obligatory (remove `?`) and wrap `.*?([A-Z]\s[A-Z]+-*[A-Z]+)` with an optional non-capturing group `(?:....)`.

```
([A-Z]+\s\d+[A-Z]*)(.+?)\s\d+\s\d+.+?(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)-(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)\s(?:.*?([A-Z]\s[A-Z]+-*[A-Z]+))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LjKmw9/2).

Comment: Hi I am reading the documentation on the site and what I got from it was basically `(?:....)` is a greedy method that will look for a pattern matching that regex first, else it will be empty? Am I correct in saying that?

Comment: A quantifier can be greedy, groups are either capturing or not, named or  numbered. `(?:PATTERN1PATTERN2...PATTERNn)?` makes a sequence of patterns optional, however, since the `?` is greedy, it is executed 1 or 0 times. Thus, the sequence of patterns inside that group is tried, and since your pattern is onbligatory inside the group it will be found if present, else, the whole group will fail, but since it is optional, the entire pattern will return a match.